# Why is the index out of range? (Python)

Tags: python

I run the code below and raise an error that says `food_quant = item[1]` list index out of range. I checked to make sure `item` was actually a list and both items are being added into the dictionary properly as well. The problem is with the `"Add"` command. Also, this is just a snippet because the rest of program is not relevant, so yes I do have proper dictionaries and lists defined above this part.

```
    item = input("Please enter an item with its quantity separated by a hyphen (Ex. Apples-3) or any of the commands described above." )
    item = item.split('-')
    food_item = item[0]
    food_quant = item[1]
    foodquant_dict[food_item] = food_quant
    if item == "Add":
        for key in foodquant_dict:
            groceryfood_list.append(key)
        print (groceryfood_list)
```

Comment: If the user types in `Add`, how many elements do you expect `item` to have after `item = item.split('-')`?

Comment: The line you report as the error in your description does not appear anywhere in the code you quoted -- did you mean `food_quant = item[1]`?

Comment: @user2357112 It should have 2 elements, such as `['Apple', '3']`

Comment: @LarryLustig Ah, yes. I fixed it.

Comment: @TaylorPatterson: Okay, so you think it should have 2 elements. What, specifically, do you think those elements would be when the user input is `Add`? Have you *tested* what that `split` call actually produces?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes it produces a list of the 2 items it was split into like `['Apple', '3']`

Comment: @TaylorPatterson: What 2 items do you think `Add` gets split into?

Comment: @user2357112 It should be an item as the first element and a number for the second element, which is what is produced.

Comment: I don't see a number in `Add`. Do you?

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not trying to do anything with the number in `"Add"`. However, it's during that command that the error pops up.

Comment: "I'm not trying to do anything with the number in `"Add"`." - but you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any input not containing at least on hyphen is given to your program (e.g. "add", or any arbitrary input not containing hyphen really), your progrma still attempts to set `food_quant = item[1]`, which doesn't exist if the input doesn't have at least one hyphen (i.e. if there's nothing to split in the list, your item will be list that contains just that one item).

An example to illustrate the point:

```
>>> case1 = "item-2".split("-")
>>> case1
['item', '2']
>>> case2 = "item".split("-")
>>> case2
['item']
```

Clearly, calling `case2[1]` for the latter case would cause `IndexError`, because there is just one element in the list. You need to validate whether your input contains dashes or not, or validate whether the split list contains more than one element. An example to validate list length:

```
item = input("enter your input\n")
item = item.split("-")
if len(item) > 1:
    a = item[1]
```

Comment: I think you mean `item=item.split("-")` or alternatively `item = input(...).split("-")`